# Using SBT to generate a JAR file name that doesn't include the Scala patch version

Tags: scala, jar, sbt

Here are the relevant lines from the `build.sbt` file:

```
sparkVersion := "2.2.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
version := "0.10.0"
artifactName := { (sv: ScalaVersion, module: ModuleID, artifact: Artifact) =>
  artifact.name + "_" + sv.full + "-" + sparkVersion.value + "_" + module.revision + "." + artifact.extension
}
```

The `$ sbt package` command generates a JAR file named `spark-daria_2.11.8-2.2.0_0.10.0.jar`.

I don't want the Scala patch version to be displayed in the generated JAR file.  How can I update the `artifactName` code to generate a file named `spark-daria_2.11-2.2.0_0.10.0.jar`?

I don't want to hardcode it like this:

```
artifact.name + "_2.11-" + sparkVersion.value + "_" + module.revision + "." + artifact.extension
```

Comment: Try `sv.binary`?

Comment: `sv.binary` worked, lol.  would have never guessed with that method name.  can you please add an answer, so I can accept it?  thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ScalaVersion#binary` has up-to-minor version string.

The (somewhat unintuitive) name refers to Scala versions with a binary compatible guarantee and is commonly seen in scripts that do cross-building

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `sbt assembly`, you can use `scalaBinaryVersion.value`.

Here's an example.

```
assemblyJarName in assembly := s"${name.value}_${scalaBinaryVersion.value}-${sparkVersion.value}_${version.value}.jar"
```

You don't need to define the `scalaBinaryVersion` variable anywhere, it's magically available in your `build.sbt` file.